# Why when pushing the character hard forward against the door after some seconds it's moving through the door?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The door is in lock state when it's red.
If I push the character forward nonstop on the W key in the middle of the door part it will not go through. But if I will push it forward nonstop on one of the red parts(The ShieldFX) of the door it will then go through the door. If I push it on the red part/s once it will not go through but when pushing pressing the W key nonstop after few seconds(1-2 seconds) it's moving through the door.

This is a screenshot of the door and this is a child that have a collider on it and also Door_Left and Door_Right have colliders also box colliders and on both the box collider trigger is off unchecked.

[image: Door]

This is a screenshot of the red part. It's a shield, Not my shield :
DoorShieldFXLocked and DoorShieldFXLocked (1)

[image: Shield]

Comment: Please create a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of a specific piece of code you are having difficulty with.  In this case, please post any code at all.  It really helps us help you.

Comment: Because the physics simulation doesn't happen all the time and isn't 100% accurate.

Comment: @Draco18s Is there other ways to stop the character then ? Maybe using a ray and calculate the distance for example if the distance is smaller then 1 then stop the character or something like that ?

Comment: Easiest way I can think of is to thicken your collider. Give it more area to check against so that as your character travels it doesn't have that brief window to slip past your collider.

Comment: How are you currently moving your player? `Update` and `transform.position=...`? Stop doing that and use `Rigidbody.Translate`

Comment: I think I found a solution that work after some tests. When the doors are unlocked colored green I'm setting the box collider Is Trigger to be checked true so the trigger will work and open the door when the character move in. And when the doors are locked colored red I'm changing the box collider Is Trigger to be false. I did some tests over and over again and it seems to be working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try to

- set the rigidbody Collision Detection of your player to Continuous

  > - Make the collider of the rigidbody a bit larger
  > - Make the physics time step smaller. What you are optimizing for us making sure that in one physics step you never move more than the
  >     entire size of the collider.
  > - Make sure the rigidbody doesn't exceed a certain speed at which you know, it can't tunnel. You can use drag for this purpose.

Taken from @Joachim_Ante in [collision detection at high speed](https://forum.unity.com/threads/collision-detection-at-high-speed.3353/)